# matplotlib 3d - beginners level

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi i can't seem to create a 3d representation with simple coordinates - i don't want the lines - (each coords different from 0 represent a finger applied on a touchscreen)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
Z =[0,2,0,5,0,0,0,0,8,0]
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Don't understand what you want and what your problem is. Please clarify.

Comment: Shouldn't you `X,Y,Z` be 2D arrays? Please check  [this link](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) and see `plot_surface` example.

Comment: It seems to me like you just want a 3D scatter plot?

Comment: `ax.scatter3D(X,Y,Z)` instead of `ax.plot_surface` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

To perform `plot_surface`, your input arrays (`X,Y,Z`) should be 2D arrays. 
In your case you are trying to feed in 1D arrays, and that is why when you 
run your code you get an empty plot with just the grids.

Here is an example of your code that will work:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
Z =[0,2,0,5,0,0,0,0,8,0]

x_plot,y_plot = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
z_plot = x_plot**2 + x_plot**2

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

ax.plot_surface(x_plot,y_plot,z_plot)

plt.show()
```

Here I have given as input 2D arrays as you can see. I have made them using `numpy.meshgrid`. The Z axis is an arbitrary value. This produces:

[image]

OR as others are suggesting, you just want a 3D scatter plot, in that case just use

```
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z)
```

and you will get

[image]